# Ruby Rails - created_at field is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, timezone, timestamp

I want to save the times in EST in my DB.  And I want rails to read it as the time stored in the DB.  I changed the settings in my config/application.rb file to this

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

And now when I save entries into the DB they are stored properly with the EST in the created_at field.  Second field is created at, this is straight from postgres:

```
4453 | 2015-08-26 20:04:07.023224 | mlb    | team_scores_first | fg     |    0 | 2015-08-24 | {"away":"NYM","home":"PHI"}                              |         1104 |         1103 |  541220 | {"away":-225.0,"home":185.0}
```

But when I get the record through rails it gives me this

```
<Line id: 4453, created_at: nil, league: "mlb", bet_type: "team_scores_first", period: "fg", book: 0, date: "2015-08-24", names: {"away"=>"NYM", "home"=>"PHI"}, away_team_id: 1104, home_team_id: 1103, game_id: 541220, line: {"away"=>-225.0, "home"=>185.0}>
```

Why is Rails returning nil for the created_at field? What change needs to be made so the created_at field can be read as the datetime stored in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

config.active_record.default_timezone determines whether to use Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is :utc.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

You don't set the actual time zone there, just if you want local or utc.

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Comment: if i change that, then rails is reading everything in UTC time zone.  i want EST

Comment: According to the docs it should do the opposite, try restarting your server. Also try setting that value to :utc and see if that gives the correct time.